# ParserError: Syntax Error at line: 1, column 29

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass, bootstrap-5

When attempting to deploy to Heroku while Heroku is running rake assets:precompile, I get this error and have no idea why.

here is the code the error is referencing: `@import "bootstrap";`

package.json

```
{
  "name": "zappys-wash",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.14.2",
    "yarn": "1.22.19"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.23.3",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.7",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.7",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.4.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.70.0",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3"
  }
}
```

https://github.com/JoeYo24/ZappysWashes

I've tried updating numerous dependencies to a result of the app no longer working in development.

Comment: `@import "bootstrap";` is not the line in your code instead you have `@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";` [Source](https://github.com/JoeYo24/ZappysWashes/blob/main/app/javascript/packs/application.scss). I am not that familiar with this but some googling shows that the tilda (`~`) tells webpacker to resolve this import like a module starting in node_modules.